# prepend the plus(+) symbol and append asterix(*) symbol to words in a query in PHP

Tags: php, string, query-string

I wonder how I can prepend the plus(+) symbol and append asterix(*) symbol to words in a query?

For instance, the query `'Car Bar'` should be `'+Car* +Bar*'`

Comment: Are you talking about strings?

Comment: @Kissaki, I think this is for FULLTEXT search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php> echo preg_replace("/\w+/", '+\0*', "Car Bar")
+Car* +Bar*
```

Comment: It's not that I do not like giving answers, but giving a ready code sample is not the best practice to teach others...

Comment: @Dogbert: Will this include words that are separeted with two or more spaces too?

Answer (score 1):

Either `explode()` a string a prepend and append your symbols on string parts and later `implode()` them, or use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace("/\w+/", "+$0*", $string);
```